# Hiding a section of WordPress theme on the homepage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have purchased a WordPress theme from [here](http://clinico.creaws.com). However, on the homepage I find this section of code that I don't want to show:

**Code:**

```
<main>
<div class="grid-row"> 
    <section class="news <?php echo $blogtype ? 'news-'. $blogtype : '';?>">
        <div class="grid isotope">
        <?php
        cws_blog_output($r, $total_post_count, $posts_per_page, $blogtype, "", $sb_block, $paged);
        ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        if ( $max_paged>1 ){
        cws_pagination($paged,$max_paged);
        }
        ?>
    </section>
</main>
```

When I try to *Inspect Element* it shows some dynamically generated classes from a javascript file. How do I remove this from the homepage? It's fine if I have to use inline-styles.

Comment: It may be an idea to check with the theme creator if they have a forum. I am a bit confused as to why you don't just delete the code if you don't want it outputting on the page.

Comment: More details would be great like which classes is it adding and what you don't want to show etc etc

Comment: Firstly create a child theme after then try to make the code changes.

Comment: Why don't you just delete the entire block from the template file?

Comment: in inspect element it shows deletable content  inside main but when i delete main from php that does not work ,

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using Clinico theme.

If you want to do certain updates in a theme(usually in third-party theme), create a child theme and do the updates over there.

Why we need to use a child theme because, frequent theme updates overwrite changes in your main theme.

Here is an example for what you need to do for removing certain sections from parent theme.

- [Read about child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).
- Create a new folder in your theme folder with name clinico-child (themename-child).
- Create a style.css file inside the child theme with following details,

```
/*
Theme Name: Clinico - Child theme
Description: Premium Medical and Health WordPress Theme. 
Theme URI: http://clinico.creaws.com/
Author: Creative Web Solutions
Template: clinico
Version: 1.6.0
Text Domain: clinico
*/
```

- Copy index.php file from parent theme and paste it inside the child theme folder.
- Remove the section which is not required.